# Joint PDF of Chi-Square & Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, descriptive-statistics

Let the independent random variables X1 and X2 be N(0,1) and $\chi^2(r)$, respectively. Let $Y_1$ = $X_1/sqrt(X_2/r)$ and $Y_2$ = $X_2$

a) Find the joint pdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

b) Determine the marginal pdf of $Y_1$ and show that $Y_1$ has a t distribution.

Thoughts: So beyond confused I don't even know where to start. I assume there must be a trick because creating a joint pdf with a chi-square distribution and a normal distribution using the traditional method seems really strenuous.

Comment: you forgot defining $Y_2$

Comment: what is your definition of the t distribution? mine is the result of the exercise.

Comment: @mookid you are correct that the t distribution should come from this exercise, but I have no idea how that happens

Comment: I think you can use copula. It will definitely solve your problem.